# Get line number from character position

Tags: text-processing

In this question [Get line number from character position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671829/get-line-number-from-character-position) I know that it is possible to, in a text file, get the line number from a character position using scripts.

Emacs has a functionality `M-x-goto-char` that positions the cursor in the character position.

My question is: Are there any UNIX utilities that composed could get the work done in an elegant way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same technique can be used with standard POSIX tools: count the number of lines up to the character position you’re interested in.

One way to do this is to use `dd` to keep the characters up to the position of interest, and `wc` to count the lines:

```
dd if=input bs=1 count=5437 | wc -l
```

This counts lines starting from 0 (*i.e.* if `wc -l` outputs 0, the character occurs on the first line).

The following variant cleans the output up and starts from 1:

```
(dd if=input bs=1 count=5437 2>/dev/null; printf "\n") | wc -l
```

Comment: I don't have `emacs`. Any idea if `emacs` `goto-char` includes newlines in the count? I know that `dd` would include newlines in `count=5437`

Comment: @iruvar `goto-char` counts newlines too, the results would be identical here.

Comment: This counts the newline at the end of line *N* as belonging to line *N* + 1.  To get the more standard interpretation (a newline belongs to the line it ends), subtract one from the byte count; e.g., use `count=5436` to identify the line containing the 5437th character. … … … … … … … Unless you’re counting characters starting at 0, in which case you should say so. … … … … P.S. [The original Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7671829/3960947) actually uses 5347, not 5437.